# Is there a limit to the number of answers that a single user can submit to the same question?

Tags: support, answers, limits

Some websites run weekly, fortnightly or monthly topic challenges, e.g. [Gardening](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/gardening-landscaping-weekly-topic-challenge), [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/what-should-be-the-subjects-of-our-fortnightly-topic-challenges) and [Literature](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/2191). On Literature Meta SE, anyone can submit reading challenges, using one answer per proposal. Of course, each user can submit more than one proposal.

My question is whether it there is a limit to the number of answers that a single user can submit to the same question (in this case a meta question). One user currently has ten reading challenge proposals on Literature Stack Exchange and cannot add any new ones. After pushing the `Add Another Answer` button, the following message appears:

> Are you sure you want to add another answer? 
>   You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

Pressing the `OK` button simply reopens the user's most recent answer for editing. Pressing `Cancel` exits the submission process.

So there appears to be a limit of ten "active" answers, since deleted answers (in this case, proposals that have been accepted and therefore deleted) don't seem to count. Is this correct? Is this a bug or a "feature"?

Comment: [Interesting SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/1079713/questions-with-the-most-answers-by-a-single-user) - there are questions here with more than 10 answers by a single user.

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks for pointing to that query. So there must be something else going on.